# memcached is not working in php 8.1 in windows 10

Tags: dll, windows-10, memcached, php-8.1

I want to add php extension for memcached. I downloaded **dll** (*8.1 Thread Safe (TS) x64*) from https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached/3.2.0RC2/windows.

Put the **php_memcached.dll** file in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext`

Put the **libhashkit.dll** and **libmemcached.dll** in *C:\Windows* and added *C:\Windows* in system path via environment variable.
Added **extension=memcached** in *php.ini* file.
And restart all services.

But the memcached extension is not showing when I check *phpinfo()*;

Am I miss something.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your PHP install is also TS and x64, as shown on the screenshot below.

If it's correct, then verify you server logs (Apache?) and PHP error logs.
You have to enable the php_error line in the PHP.INI (ie. error_log ="c:/Apache24/logs/php_error.log").

[image]